# How do I find all documents with all elements of an embedded array matching a certain condition?

Tags: mongodb

I want to write a query that returns all of the `Foo` objects that do NOT have all of their `bar` objects with complete set to `true`.

Here are the objects I'm dealing with:

```
> db.Foo.find()
[
  {
    name: "foo1",
    bars: [
      { 
         name: "bar1", complete: true
      },
      { 
         name: "bar2", complete: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "foo2",
    bars: [
      { 
         name: "barbo", complete: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "foo3",
    bars: [
      { 
         name: "barbie", complete: true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In this case, I would want the query to return only `foo1` and `foo2`.

I've tried `db.Foo.find({ "bars.complete": { $ne: false } })`, which gives me the opposite of what I want (in this case, it returns `foo1` and `foo2`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I completely confused myself before, and ended up having to change the question to be what I was looking for.  Here's how I solved it:

```
db.Foo.find({ "bars.complete": false })
```